# How do I trigger events after event handlers are bound in ajax calls when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

### Problem:

I've got 2 drop downs, both populated by information from a database and dependent on some initial information (a json array created in php). The second drop down is also dependent on what was selected in the first dropdown. Once the second dropdown has been selected, the users selections are saved in another database table. If the user leaves and then comes back, I want to be able to reset the drop downs to what they previously selected (but still let them change their selections).

### Context:

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
function eventHandler2(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "someotherurl.php",
        data: event.data["context"],
        success: function(data) {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    });
}

function eventHandler1(event) {
    event.data["context"][$(event.target).id()] = $(event.target).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl.php",
        data: event.data["context"],
        success: function(data) {
            $("#element").append(build_input("input2", data));
            $("#element input2").change({"context": event.data["context"]}, eventHandler2);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var context = // php generated json array.
    $("#element").append(build_input("input1", context));
    $("#element input1").change({"context": context}, eventHandler1);
});
```

`context` includes some data that has to be initialized outside of the event handler and is added to durring events, and `build_input` just returns an html string of a form input element built with options determined by `data` or `someData`. At times the entire html element that includes eventHandler1 (and eventHandler2) will be removed and reinitialized.

My issue is that I want to initialize the two form inputs (built using build_input) with some default values pulled from a database, but once those values have been set I don't want any reinitialization or event handling to use those initial values (which makes adding them to the context object difficult since that object will be used when binding the event handlers).

I would like to set the value for the inputs and then call a change event to simulate a user selecting those values, but because the input elements are built using ajax data, those change events are being getting called before the ajax request have returned and built the input elements.

I could solve this with timeouts, but because the the javascript might run slower on different machines and the ajax calls could take longer than normal, I don't plan on doing it that way. Still, ideally I would like something like this:

```
$("#element .input1 option[value='" + initial_value + "']").attr('selected', true);
$("#element .input1").change();
```

to be called when the page loads but only after the elements have been built and bound.

### Question:

Is there any way to trigger change events (simulating the user selecting options) only when the page is first loaded and only after the ajax request to build the html input elements have returned?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way to trigger change events (simulating the user selecting options) only when the

> page is first loaded

and only

> after the ajax request

to build the html input elements have returned?

These are two separate events. If you need to ensure both events have ocurred use `<body onload="loadedBody=true">` and take advantage of the success: attribute of the `$.ajax` function like this:

```
function eventHandler1(event) {
    event.data["context"][$(event.target).id()] = $(event.target).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl.php",
        data: event.data["context"],
        success: function(data) {
            $("#element").append(build_input("input2", data));
            $("#element input2").change({"context": event.data["context"]}, eventHandler2);
            ajaxComplete();
        }
    });
}
var ajaxCompleted;
function ajaxComplete() {
    if((loadedBody == true) && (ajaxCompleted == false)) {
        $("#element .input1 option[value='" + initial_value + "']").attr('selected', true);
        $("#element .input1").change();
    } else {
        setTimeout('ajaxComplete()', 100);
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the setTimeout. It will rarely be used because the page will likely have loaded before the AJAX result arrives.

Comment: Thanks. Recursive setTimeouts would work (although I'd probably want to include some counter so that the setTimeout loop 'timesout' after so many tries). I ended up firing a custom event from the success event and using the .one() event binder to handle that custom event only the first time it is fired. The code seems to work fine but is a little hard to read so I might end up reworking it in a way that may be more similar to your solution.